# Load assembly from same folder with a native DLL

Tags: .net, c++, com, interop, .net-assembly

I have this (native) COM server, let's call it **N.dll**, that calls some API from a managed assembly, let's call it **M.dll**. For that to work, a mixed-mode DLL exists to interop the two; let's call this **MM.dll**. The three DLLs (N, M and MM) reside in the same DLL, and the COM server is obviously appropriately register.

I'm using the M.dll assembly with a using directive in MM.dll.

```
#using "M.dll"
using namespace M;
```

And then just instantiate and use the types available in M.

Now, this COM server can be instantiated by any application, residing anywhere in the system. That, obviously works all right. But as soon as N needs to call the API from M (via MM), I get an `System.IO.FileNotFoundException` (Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'M, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.)

If I copy the M.dll assembly to the same folder where the executable is, then everything works fine. However, this is not a solution, since there can be a lot of apps consuming the COM server, and I cannot deploy M.dll to all those places. And I also cannot do something with a config file for the process, for the same reason. I need a way to tell the mixed-mode MM.dll module to load the managed assembly from the same folder where it is located.

Is that possible?

Comment: One quick solution might be modifying the systems PATH-variable to include the location of your COM server and it's sub components.

Comment: You have no attractive options here but one, deploy the managed assembly to the GAC.  Give it a strong name first.

Comment: Well, of course, deploying to GAC would work, but due to some particular requirements I can't do that. So it looks like I'm stuck with reflection.

Answer (score 0):

See the discussion on how Windows locates DLL's on msdn ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586(v=vs.85).aspx ). When loading the COM server, the dependant DLL must be located by windows. Make sure that the search algorithm will find the dependant DLL's.

Comment: At least on my developer machine, the folder where N, M and MM are located is added to the PATH environment variable, still the managed assembly is not found. (However, this will not be true for the customer machines.)

Comment: In that case, ignore my comment above.

Comment: Maybe the .net system ignores the PATH-environment variable. See the discussion of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684179(v=vs.85).aspx . Maybe .net could be told not to ignore the PATH variable. I lack the time to find out how for you (unfortunately).

Comment: Well, I can fix this problem with reflection, I can load the assembly from a specific path, but then I have to write a lot of code. With the using directive it's all so simple.